# change spacedallcaps and spacedlowsmallcaps to something like spacedsmallcaps (classicthesis)

Tags: formatting, chapters, classicthesis, small-caps, letterspacing

Instead of `\spacedallcaps` and `\spacedlowsmallcaps` would like to have big and small capitals (like `\scshape`) but keep the definitions for space between the letters, size, colour, ...

With `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\scshape #1}` I change everything.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
listings,manychapters,%
floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 
% \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\scshape #1}
% \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\scshape #1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chapter title formatting is labelled in [`classicthesis.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty) as "Fancy Stuff":

```
% ********************************************************************
% Fancy Stuff
% ********************************************************************  
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % for better rules in tables
\RequirePackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@minionprospacing}}%
    {%
        \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{Using MinionPro's textssc for character spacing.}%
        \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textssc{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
        \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textssc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@pdfspacing}}%
        {%
            \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{Using pdftex/microtype for character spacing.%
                                        Make sure your pdftex is version 1.40 or higher.}%
            \microtypesetup{expansion=false}%
            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textls[160]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
        }{%
            \RequirePackage{soul} % for letterspacing 
                \sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
                \sodef\lowsmallcapsspacing{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%   
                \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}}%   
                \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{\lowsmallcapsspacing{#1}}}}%\protect
        }%
    }
```

From here you can see the text spacing - given by `\textls` for `l`etter `s`pacing from [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) - that is used and could adopt it in your (re)definition of `\spacedallcaps`. Perhaps something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
  footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
  BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[parts,beramono,eulerchapternumbers,%
  listings,manychapters,%
  floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textls[160]{\scshape #1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-18]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```